# Outgoing SSH doesn't work even though I have opened the port

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, iptables

I am trying to allow outgoing SSH in my script, but when I test it, it doesn't react.

I do it by: `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -j ACCEPT`

Incoming SSH works fine and I am doing the same but just with

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

Is it because I only allow icoming established connections?:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said. The reply to your outgoing SSH will be *from* port 22, and not *to* port 22, but to the random port that was chosen with the initial outgoing connection. So no rule will match. And I suppose you have a default policy of DROP else there wouldn't be this question.

Just add the same rule to the OUTPUT chain:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

That's this rule that turns the firewall "stateful" by using conntrack to automatically allow the reverse flow.